Embed top 3 LinkedIn feeds of the organization in my SharePoint Page
I want to embed top 3 LinkedIn feeds of the organization in my SharePoint Page. In Power Automate I could see a LinkedIn connector but with that it is not possible to fetch data from LinkedIn.
Please guide me step by step to fetch top 3posts without depending on any third-party applications like Sociablekit.

You can fetch LinkedIn data using power automate periodically, store in SharePoint list and display this data in site page.

There is currently no options available to fetch data directly using LinkedIn Connector in Power Automate. There are only options to post data. Please help if you have any idea how to implement the same

Is there any API available from LinkedIn side to get these feeds? If Yes, then you can use HTTP connectors (as a REST API) in the Power Automate flow to get the data. And rest of the approach will be same. Also, for these APIs, you will have to contact LinkedIn support/community.
